# jq: syntax error, unexpected ':' using jq for input?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am trying to build an array using jq:  https://jqplay.org/s/MSk-uUDrRU

When I attempt this in the wild, using a jq command like:

```
echo "[]" | jq -r --arg arg1 $(aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/MyPolicy --version-id v2 | jq -r --arg arg2 "MyPolicy" '.entity + {"PolicyName": $arg2}') '.[.|length] |= . + $arg1'
```

I get an error message like:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
"CreateDate":            
jq: 1 compile error
```

This code that is in $arg1 prints out to a file okay.

```
aws <long calling argument> | jq -r --arg arg2 "MyPolicy" '.entity + {"PolicyName": $arg2}'
```

The AWS command is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-policy-version.html

Please note, this is all wrapped in a loop to build an array of the policy versions in which I'm interested.  The `"[]"` is initially defined in variable outside of the loop.

Comment: You probably don't need `jq`; `aws` supports JMESPath queries to manipulate the result before it is output.

Comment: @chepner, Thank you.  I will investigate that.

Comment: `.[.| length] |= . + {"type": "name"}` can be shortened to
`.[length] = {"type": "name"}` or even better: `. + [{type: "name"}]`

Comment: The inner jq looks OK, but what is the STDIN input to the outer jq?

Comment: Hi @peak the output of the inner jq is `{ "PolicyVersion": { "CreateDate": "2015-06-17T19:23;32Z", "VersionId": "v2", "Document": { "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Action": "iam:*", "Resource": "*", "Effect": "Allow" } ] } "IsDefaultVersion": "false", "PolicyName": "MyPolicy"}}`

Answer (score 1):

Use --argjson instead of --arg in the outer invocation.  So, breaking things up for clarity, you would have:

```
output=$(aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/MyPolicy --version-id v2 | jq -r --arg arg2 "MyPolicy" '.entity + {"PolicyName": $arg2}' )

jq -rn --argjson arg1 "$output" '. + [$arg1]'
```

With the JSON shown in the comment, this would produce:

```
[
  {
    "PolicyName": "MyPolicy"
  }
]
```

I would also suggest that you try to avoid calling jq twice, e.g. along the lines of:

```
aws ... | 
  jq --arg arg2 MyPolicy '[.entity + {"PolicyName": $arg2}]'
```

Comment: Hi @peak.  I have added the initial input into the question.  I have to disagree, about jq operating on the output of jq at least in the context of the first jq outputting valid json.  The purpose of this code is to collate, json object api responses into an array of json objects.  Such that an api which outputs `{"object"}` is transformed to `{"object": "id"}` and then collated into `[{"object": "1"},{"object": "2"},{"object": "3"}]`.  I tried your method above and unfortunately it did not succeed.  Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the jqplay link to match the scenario more closely.  The only differences now are that it doesn't feed from jq into jq and its all on one line.